# Saving a WFS layer directly to the disk using QGIS or PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, wfs

I know how to properly load a layer in QGIS from a WFS service, but I would like to directly save it to a `.shp` file (without the preliminary loading of it into QGIS).

Is it possible to do this within QGIS or with a PyQGIS script?

A sample URL from which starting would be this one:

```
http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Carta_geologica.map
```

having these [capabilities](http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Carta_geologica.map&service=wfs&request=getCapabilities).

Comment: could you just use ogr2ogr?

Comment: @iant Potentially yes, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that without PyQGIS (e.g., downloading the GML from the WFS to your disk and then converting it to Shapefile through `ogr`), but since you would like to do it with PyQGIS (why not?), try this:

```
uri = "http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Carta_geologica.map&request=GetFeature&Version=1.1.0&Service=WFS&typename=GE.CARTAGEOLOGICA"
layer = QgsVectorLayer( uri, "my wfs layer", "WFS" )
res = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer,
                                               '/tmp/wfs_features.shp',
                                               'System', # encoding
                                               None, #crs
                                               'ESRI Shapefile'
       )

if res != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print 'Error number:', res
else:
    print "WFS saved!"
```

Note that we are not loading the layer into the QGIS canvas, we are just using and intermediate `layer` object that QGIS can convert to other formats.

---

**EDIT**

Since your WFS server only works with version 1.1.0 of the WFS specification, and given the issues with axis orientation for such version, you can do this in QGIS >= v2.16 to invert axis order and get your data correctly positioned:

```
dsu = QgsDataSourceURI()
dsu.setParam( 'url', 'http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Carta_geologica.map' )
dsu.setParam( 'version', '1.1.0' )
dsu.setParam( 'typename', 'GE.CARTAGEOLOGICA' )
dsu.setParam( 'InvertAxisOrientation', '1' )
layer = QgsVectorLayer( dsu.uri(), "my wfs layer", "WFS" )

res = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer,
                                               '/tmp/wfs_features.shp',
                                               'System', # encoding
                                               None, #crs
                                               'ESRI Shapefile'
       )

if res != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print 'Error number:', res
else:
    print "WFS saved!"
```

Comment: It works but I obtain a wrong result (linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLKnA.png)). Even using `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)` instead of `None` for the `crs`, the result is the same: what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: note the axis flipping I mentioned below is what causes this too

Comment: @iant Thanks, I was thinking the same and I'm trying to understand how to apply it to my case =)

Comment: Just updated my answer with a way to invert the axis orientation, which is a known issue for WFS < v1.1.1.

Comment: When I run this script, I get the following error: ```Error number: (8, '') ``` What does this mean?

Answer (score 6):

If you are happy to use the command line then `ogr2ogr` is the best tool for saving WFS outputs to shapefiles.

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' cartageologica WFS:"http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Carta_geologica.map" GE.CARTAGEOLOGICA
```

Will create a folder called `cartageologica` containing a shapefile called `GE.CARTAGEOLOGICA.shp`.

Having tested that shapefile you may need to do

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +axis=neu +wktext"
    -t_srs "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +axis=enu +wktext" dest.shp source.shp
```

to flip the axis order (as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/ogr2ogr-specify-lat-long-order-on-conversion-to-geojson))

Comment: Sorry, I thought I have read `gdal` instead of `ogr2ogr`. However, I tried to run your command from the OSGeo4W Shell (I'm unfamiliar with it), but I get the error: `Unable to open datasource C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\`  `(this happens even if I change the working directory to `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\`

Comment: That sounds like a windows setup issue, I'm afraid I'm a linux guy :-(

Comment: I'm sure it's a slight mistake, but at this moment I can't solve it so I can't test your solution. I'll continue to do some test, hoping to accept the answer if it works. However, thanks and +1 for the effort.