# Automating WFS to Shapefile Export using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, wfs

I'm trying to write a simple script to automate the download of several hundred WFS services and create shapefiles. All of these services have the same URL, e.g.: https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_Induktionsschleife while only the last word is changing from file to file. The shapefiles are supposed to be named with a certain structure based on that last word of the URL, e.g. Senat_Induktionsschleife_25833.shp.

Unfortunately, it only creates empty shapefiles, the WFS services fails to load. If I print and copy the created URI and add the WFS manually, it works, so the URI is created correctly.

```
id = "Induktionsschleife"
uri = r"https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_" +id + "?srsname=EPSG:25833&typename=fis:s_" +id + "+&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature"
outputPath = '/Users/XXXX/Desktop/WFS-Download/' + 'Senat_' + id + '_25833.shp'

lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Temp", "WFS")

pfad = outputPath
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, pfad, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')

name = pfad.split('/') [-1].replace('.shp', '')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(pfad, name, "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

I'm very new to Python and am not able to find out what's the problem with my code.

Do you have any suggestions?

I'm using QGIS 3.6 on MacOS 10.14.

Comment: is lyr valid? does it show on the map?

Comment: If I print my URI it creates a valid link, but lyr also stays empty when trying to add it to the map.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224274/saving-a-wfs-layer-directly-to-the-disk-using-qgis-or-pyqgis

Comment: For WFS version 2.0.0 you should be using `typenames` not `typename`.   Also the request string is missing the mandatory  service parameter `service=WFS&` and as `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:25833` is the default coordinate system you don't need to specify srs name.   Try:  `https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_Induktionsschleife?typenames=fis:s_Induktionsschleife&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&`

Comment: I wrote a more simple version of the script before without the "id" variable and that one works perfectly fine with the URI my more "advanced" code generates. Somehow the ' lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Temp", "WFS")' doesnt accept the chained URI expression.

Comment: And it's also not working with "typenameS" and "service=wfs".