# Downloading lots of data from WFS

Tags: python, pyqgis, ogr2ogr

The problem is I have a lot of data to download from a WFS. I've tried this method with different errors on the way. First I tried PyQGIS with this script:

```
uri = "http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map"
layer = QgsVectorLayer( uri, "my wfs layer", "WFS" )
crs=QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
res = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( layer,
                                                r'G..path...\edifita.shp',
                                               'System', # encoding
                                               crs, #crs
                                              'ESRI Shapefile'
       )

if res != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print ('Error number:', res)
else:
    print ("WFS saved!")
```

I extracted from here: [Saving a WFS layer directly to the disk using QGIS or PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224274/saving-a-wfs-layer-directly-to-the-disk-using-qgis-or-pyqgis)

This method gives me the following error:

```
exec(open('C:/Users/JORDI~1.PAG/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpac2ti1a7.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
Error number: (8, '')
```

Also, I tried this other method from the same source:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "...path..." WFS:"http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map"
```

However, it gives me these 2 errors:

```
ERROR 1: HTTP error code : 504                                                                                                                     ERROR 1: Error returned by server : HTTP error code : 504 (0)
```

I am not sure if the errors are caused by the large amount of data or something else.

What do you think?

Comment: 504 is a gateway timeout. Your best approach would be to look at OFFSET and LIMIT to request parts of the data

Comment: I've tried this, but I still get the same error: ```ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "...path..." WFS:"http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map" ``` 
If I download 0-100, how do I resume the download in the 101-x if I downloaded 0-100?

Comment: Have you already read about paging https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html?

Comment: I get a timeout requesting just one feature.  Points to some misconfiguration on the server; possibly the data source is not available

Comment: Requesting one feature is fast for me `http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI.&maxfeatures=1`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the WFS server itself and not with your approach. To explain that lets look at it step by step.

WFS url is : http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map

Before downloading the data lets see the description of this WFS service and see what all layers are part of this source using a read only `ogrinfo` call.

```
ogrinfo  WFS:"http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map"
```

This command returns

```
INFO: Open of `WFS:http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map'
      using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=Edificato dei capoluoghi di provincia. I capoluoghi di provincia rappresentati sono quelli relativi all'anno 2003. Scala 1:10.000
  PROVIDER_NAME=Geoportale Nazionale - Ministero dell'Ambiente e della Tutela del Territorio e del Mare
  TITLE=Edificato dei capoluoghi di provincia
1: ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI. (title: Edificato) (Multi Surface)
```

which mentions that there is 1 layer with a name "ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI." and it has a Multi Surface geometry.

Next, we try to load metadata of this layer, to see what are the extents, coordinate system etc, information for the layer  "ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI." using the same `ogrinfo` command and passing the layer name in the end.

```
ogrinfo  WFS:"http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map" ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI.
```

This gives the following output

```
INFO: Open of `WFS:http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map'
      using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=Edificato dei capoluoghi di provincia. I capoluoghi di provincia rappresentati sono quelli relativi all'anno 2003. Scala 1:10.000
  PROVIDER_NAME=Geoportale Nazionale - Ministero dell'Ambiente e della Tutela del Territorio e del Mare
  TITLE=Edificato dei capoluoghi di provincia

Layer name: ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI.
Metadata:
  ABSTRACT=La tabella associata contiene le seguenti informazioni principali: id_edifici, identificativo unico dell'edificio; quota_suolo, quota del suolo espressa in metri sul livello del mare; quota_gronda, quota della gronda dell'edificio espressa in metri sul livello del mare; altezza, altezza dell'edificio espressa in metri sul livello del mare; tipologia, tipologia di edificio espressa da un valore numerico variabile tra 1 e 4; area_, area di base dell'edificio espressa in metri quadri;perimetro, perimetro di base dell'edificio espresso in metri.
  KEYWORD_1=Edifici
  KEYWORD_2=Edilizia
  KEYWORD_3=Edificio
  TITLE=Edificato
Geometry: Multi Surface
ERROR 1: HTTP error code : 504
ERROR 1: Error returned by server : HTTP error code : 504 (0)
```

You see the WFS server is getting timed out while downloading the Metadata of the layer itself and hence the `ogr2ogr` is also failing while downloading the actual data irrespective of whatever pagination options you provide.

This is a WFS server issue, I can only make a guess that the data is hosted on a Mapserver but it is proxied with a web server like NGINX or Apache and the connection between the webserver and geoserver is probably timing out. As far as an alternative is concerned, I don't see a solution unless this is fixed by the server itself.

Comment: With `map=` it is almost certainly MapServer not GeoServer, possibly QGIS server. but the  DescribeFeatureType response for `http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map&service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0`  points to a MapServer schema

Comment: Yes correct, its a mapserver and not geoserver. Updated that part.

Comment: The problem is not in the metadata from DescribeFeatureType but ogrinfo wants to know the total number of features and therefore is sends this request `WFS: http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI.&RESULTTYPE=hits`

Comment: Server announces in GetCapabilities that `&resulttype=hits` is supported but what it hits is timeout. I suggest to inform the service provider.

Answer (score 5):

I am having trouble loading the *Edifici* service you have linked, both through QGIS, Python and browser. The GetCapabilities document is loading, but the content is not.

I have tried with another service from the same site that works fine.

*Alluvioni_Estensione* from http://www.pcn.minambiente.it/mattm/en/wfs-service/

I have had success saving large WFS requests from other services using code similar to this:

```
from requests import Request
import geopandas as gpd

#url = 'http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map&service=wfs&request=getFeature&version=1.0.0&typename=ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI.'
url = 'http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Alluvioni_Estensione.map&service=wfs&request=getFeature&version=1.0.0&typename=ITH2018_Estensione_HPH'

q = Request('GET', url).prepare().url
df = gpd.read_file(q, format='GML')
df.crs = 'EPSG:4326'

df.to_file('output.shp')
```

Comment: Note the request parameter values are case sensitive, so it should be `WFS` not `wfs` for your service value, and `GetFeature` not `getFeature`

Answer (score 2):

That server does not behave quite as GDAL believes it does. If you really need to get the data you can do it with manual paging. Even if the server supports only WFS 1.1.0 and paging was introduced in WFS 2.0.0 that server (it is MapServer) supports &StartIndex as a vendor option. That is documented in GDAL documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html

> Some servers (such as MapServer >= 6.0) support the use of STARTINDEX
> that allows doing the requests per “page”, and thus to avoid
> downloading the whole content of the layer in a single request. Paging
> was introduced in WFS 2.0.0 but servers may support it as an vendor
> specific option also with WFS 1.0.0 and 1.1.0.

1. First request that starts from the beginning

http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI.&maxfeatures=1000

Save response into file

2. Second request

http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=ED.EDIFICATO.CAPOLUOGHI.&MaxFeatures=1000&StartIndex=1000

Save response into file

3. Following requests:

Increase the StartIndex value

When you have collected all batches combine the results, for example

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg wfs.gpkg batch1.gml -nln data_from_wfs
ogr2ogr -f gpkg -update -append wfs.gpkg batch2.gml -nln data_from_wfs
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to fetch data from that service by using the alternative way to make a connection to WFS server with a GDAL WFS-XML file as documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html

> It is also possible to specify the name of an XML file whose content
> matches the following syntax (the  element must be
> the first bytes of the file): ...
>
> The service description file has the
> following additional elements as immediate children of the
> OGRWFSDataSource element that may be optionally set. ...
>
> **PagingAllowed**: Set to ON if paging must be enabled. See “Request
> paging” section.
> **PageSize**: Page size when paging is enabled. See “Request paging”
> section.

Copy and paste the following text and save it as "wfs.xml" on your computer.

```
<OGRWFSDataSource>
  <URL>http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Edifici.map</URL>
  <PagingAllowed>ON</PagingAllowed>
  <PageSize>1000</PageSize>
  <WFS_Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
</OGRWFSDataSource>
```

Next run command

```
ogrinfo wfs.xml
```

Open the wfs.xml file, it should have now much more data.
Then you can convert all the data from the WFS service into GeoPackage with command

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg wfs.gpkg wfs.xml
```

If you want to follow what GDAL is doing use command

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg wfs.gpkg wfs.xml --debug on
```

By the documentation it should also be possible to give the PagingAllowed and PageSize options from the command line as config options. I tried that without success but maybe I used somehow wrong syntax.